# While opening the jss app item in experience editor getting Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat

Tags: jss

Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer:

```
       EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\sitecore' Error: EPERM:
operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\sitecore' at Object.realpathSync
    (fs.js:1529:7) at toRealPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:334:13)
         at tryFile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:330:22) at tryExtensions
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:342:22) at Function.Module._findPath
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:517:20) at Function.Module._resolveFilename
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:27) at Function.Module._load
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27) at Module.require
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19) at require
    (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
        at C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\1gnoggkx.yj3:113:33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an issue with permissions at site parent folder level. Assigning permissions to this IIS user(NetworkService in this case) to the parent folder(**D:Sitecore**\sites\Mysite include sub folders) where the site is located fixed the issue.